# UnityPlayer crashes on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

Facing the crash while debugging the application on Windows Phone 8 (Nokia Lumia 520), and I cannot figure out why. The game is developed in Unity, targeting iOS and Android at first, and now being ported to WP8. The failure occurs before stepping into my scripts, and `UnhandledException` handler also isn't reached.

Debugger (Native Only) is set to break when exception is thrown and user-unhandled. At first time call stack is:

```
KERNELBASE.DLL!RaiseException() Unknown
coreclr.dll!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly(class Object *,int,int)   Unknown
coreclr.dll!UnwindAndContinueRethrowHelperAfterCatch(class Frame *,class Exception *)   Unknown
coreclr.dll!AssemblyNative::GetType(struct QCall::AssemblyHandle,unsigned short const *,int,int,struct QCall::ObjectHandleOnStack)  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!702d7056()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!702d7056()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!702d7056()  Unknown
...
```

(Cannot load mscorlib.ni.pdb, so stack frames are not symbolized).
Right after next break call stack contains:

```
KERNELBASE.DLL!RaiseException() Unknown
Msvcr110.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject=0x06a9fc24, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 152  C++
Vccorlib110.dll!__abi_WinRTraiseCOMException(long hr=-2146234304) Line 502  C++
UnityPlayer.dll!ScriptingTypeProvider_Metro::NativeTypeFor(const char * namespaze=0x05f2d228, const char * name=0x05ba0aa0) Line 29 C++
UnityPlayer.dll!ScriptingTypeRegistry::GetType(const char * namespaze=0x06a9fd88, const char * name=0x05f2d2ac) Line 19 C++
UnityPlayer.dll!MonoScript::RebuildFromAwake() Line 149 C++
UnityPlayer.dll!PersistentManager::LoadFileCompletelyThreaded(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,stl_allocator<char,51,4> > & pathname={...}, int * fileIDs=0x06a9fec8, int * instanceIDs=0x00010004, int size=-1, bool loadScene=false, LoadProgress * loadProgress=0x06a9fec8) Line 1452 C++
UnityPlayer.dll!PreloadLevelOperation::Perform() Line 652   C++
UnityPlayer.dll!PreloadManager::Run() Line 235  C++
UnityPlayer.dll!PreloadManager::Run(void * managerPtr=0x03d91540) Line 187  C++
UnityPlayer.dll!Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void * ptr=0xfffffffe) Line 44 C++
UnityPlayer.dll!<lambda_14163fd8e7b3473ba35abd0bcfa8d126>::operator()(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^ __formal=0x05be84a8) Line 273 C++
UnityPlayer.dll!Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler::[Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler::__abi_IDelegate]::__abi_Windows_System_Threading_WorkItemHandler___abi_IDelegate____abi_Invoke(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^ __param0=0x03d91528)  C++
THREADPOOLWINRT.DLL!Windows::System::Threading::CThreadPoolWorkItem::CommonWorkCallback(void)   Unknown
THREADPOOLWINRT.DLL!Windows::System::Threading::CThreadPoolWorkItem::TimeSlicedCallback(void *) Unknown
NTDLL.DLL!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

And the output says:

```
First-chance exception at 0x77271ECF in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x06A9FC24. HRESULT:0x80131040
```

If I correctly interpret Google results for "HRESULT:0x80131040" it's often associated with message "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference." How can I find out what assembly causes the problem? Which ways should I try to investigate this issue?

Environment:

- Windows Pro 8.1 64-bit
- Unity Pro 4.3.1f1
- Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone (supplied with Windows Phone SDK 8.0)

Related question: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/595091/windows-phone-8-debugger.html

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tautvydas Zilys [surmised](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/218050-UnityPlayer-dll-throws-Platform-COMException?p=1455971) that the cause was mismatch between versions of assemblies of the same name that targeted different platforms; and he was right.